# Weird behavior with Runtime.exec

Tags: java, eclipse

I start another application from within my Java app using runtime.exec. That child program starts no problems but when I call system.exit(0); from the parent app the parents JVM keeps running until the child program is terminated.

Here is a simple example:

```
    public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try{
             Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
             Process p=runtime.exec("cmd /c \"client.exe\"");
             Thread.sleep(10000);
             System.exit(0);
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

I want the child app to continue running after System.exit is called and for Test apps JVM to shutdown completely.

In eclipse I get this behavior:

After the Test app starts, client.exe starts up immediately. After the 10 second sleep the app exits but from the eclipse console the Test app is still running. More strange hitting the red terminate button at this point does nothing. Yet as soon as client.exe is closed the parent Test app finally terminates.

However even more strange if I hit the red terminate button in the eclipse console BEFORE the 10 second sleep elapses then the Test App closes and the client.exe keeps on running. This is the behavior I want but I can't figure out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default behaviour of most OS's, that a parent process can't terminate until all child processes have terminated.

Now, there is a "funky" way to create a "parentless" process, so that the parent process can terminate and the child process will continue running, but this becomes OS dependent, which you already have any way...

Basically, the command lines becomes something like...

```
cmd /C start /B /NORMAL cmd /c "client.exe"
```

Now.  I would recommend that you use the `Runtime#exec(String[])` variant, as this deals with spaces within commands better

```
String[] cmd = {"cmd", "/C", "start", "/B", "/NORMAL", "cmd", "/c", "client.exe"};
runtime.exec(cmd);
```

Normally, I would recommend `ProcessBuilder` over `Runtime#exec`, as it allows you to, amongst other things, change the working directory for the process...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I replaced the runtime.exec with what you'd suggested (Runtime#exec(String[]) and while the client.exe still starts I get the same behavior with the JVM staying open. Certainly you've provided somewhere for me to start. Thanks Again!

Comment: Really, because we use this solution as part of our update process and it works very well

Comment: I replaced client.exe with explorer.exe and it works fine. I think it might have something to do with my path and the fact that the real file (client.exe) has a space in the filename. Thank you again for your answer.

Comment: Oh, just remembered...this process doesn't like long file names or paths!  It has something to do with `cmd`.  I ended up having to use a small amount of JNI to convert the paths and file names to 8.3 format, just beware...